# Segmentation Fault on strtol with in pthread function

Tags: c, xcode, terminal, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am getting a "Segmentation Fault 11" on the following block of code inside of a pthread:

```
void *func(void *len){
    char *temp = len;
    size = (int) strtol(temp, (char **)NULL, 10); // this throws the segfault
}
```

The pthread create is written as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    pthread_t t0;
    const char * length = argv[1];

    pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &func, (void *)length);
    // rest of code
    ...
}
```

What is confusing me is that the SegFault is being thrown when compiled and ran in the terminal but not in Xcode. Any idea on why it is being thrown?

Comment: Are you calling function func from other threads as well ?

Comment: How are you using `length` in `main()` after having it passed to `pthread_create()`? And what is `size`?

Comment: You do **not** test `temp` for being differnt from `NULL` before passing it to `strtol()`. Also you might like to use `argc` to test whether `argv[1]` does contain any valid reference.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you wait for the thread, it may be the case that `main()` exits before `func()` is even executed (so `argv` is then invalidated, since it's out of scope there). My guess is that this is a race condition which is eliminated when run inside a debugger, and that's why running it "in Xcode" (it's not the IDE that matters, rather the fact that the process is being debugged) helps.

Comment: I use **pthread_join** later on in the rest of the code section to wait. Sorry I should have included this. That should prevent the issue you stated right?

Comment: @wbcrimson Yes, that should. Then you have other errors in the code as well.